# Custom GradientDrawable doesn't work on Android Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-custom-view, android-drawable, gradientdrawable

I want to use RingDrawable in my android application (no xml).

I found this code **RingDrawable.java**, but it doesn't work on Android Lollipop. There is simply no effect at all. 
Could you tell me please how to improve this?
Thank you!

```
public class RingDrawable extends GradientDrawable {

    private Class<?> mGradientState;

    public RingDrawable() {
        this(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, null);
    }

    public RingDrawable(int innerRadius, int thickness, float innerRadiusRatio, float thicknessRatio) {
        this(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, null, innerRadius, thickness, innerRadiusRatio, thicknessRatio);
    }

    public RingDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation, int[] colors) {
        super(orientation, colors);
        setShape(RING);
    }

    public RingDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation, int[] colors, int innerRadius, int thickness, float innerRadiusRatio, float thicknessRatio) {
        this(orientation, colors);
        try {
            setInnerRadius(innerRadius);
            setThickness(thickness);
            setInnerRadiusRatio(innerRadiusRatio);
            setThicknessRatio(thicknessRatio);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // fail silently - change to your own liking
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setInnerRadius(int radius) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (mGradientState == null) mGradientState = resolveGradientState();
        Field innerRadius = resolveField(mGradientState, "mInnerRadius");
        innerRadius.setInt(getConstantState(), radius);
    }       

    public void setThickness(int thicknessValue) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (mGradientState == null) mGradientState = resolveGradientState();
        Field thickness = resolveField(mGradientState, "mThickness");
        thickness.setInt(getConstantState(), thicknessValue);
    }

    public void setInnerRadiusRatio(float ratio) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (mGradientState == null) mGradientState = resolveGradientState();
        Field innerRadiusRatio = resolveField(mGradientState, "mInnerRadiusRatio");
        innerRadiusRatio.setFloat(getConstantState(), ratio);
    }

    public void setThicknessRatio(float ratio) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        if (mGradientState == null) mGradientState = resolveGradientState();
        Field thicknessRatio = resolveField(mGradientState, "mThicknessRatio");
        thicknessRatio.setFloat(getConstantState(), ratio);
    }

    private Class<?> resolveGradientState() {
        Class<?>[] classes = GradientDrawable.class.getDeclaredClasses();
        for (Class<?> singleClass : classes) {
            if (singleClass.getSimpleName().equals("GradientState")) return singleClass;
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("GradientState could not be found in current GradientDrawable implementation");
    }

    private Field resolveField(Class<?> source, String fieldName) throws SecurityException, NoSuchFieldException {
        Field field = source.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field;
    }

}
```